# App is crashing on receiving a GCM push notification in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

My app is crashing on receiving GCM push notification

Permission in AndroidMainfest.xml are:

```
<!-- [START gcm_permission] -->
<permission
    android:name="com.cik.gcmpush.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.cik.gcmpush.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

<!-- Permission to vibrate -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<!-- All of the following are required by GCM Receiver or Sender, End -->


<!-- Optional permission for Google Analytics -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!-- [END gcm_permission] -->
```

And I customized sendNotification() function in MyGcmListenerService.

Comment: where is your logcat?

Comment: post your `MyGcmListenerService.java` code and logcat